# Регулярное выражение: проверка длины строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо, чтобы регулярное выражение возвращало `false` если длина строки (с учетом пробелов) больше 3 и `true`, если `<=`
Накидал регулярки, все что смог сам сделать и те, что смог найти в инете  - ничего не получается

```js
const text = "123 56"
const patterns = [
    /.{1,3}/ig, 
    /.{1,3}$/ig, 
    /.{1,3}(?!.)/ig, 
    /[\w\s]{1,3}/ig, 
    /[\w\s]{1,3}(?![\w\s])/ig, 
    /[\w\s]{1,3}(?!\w\s)/ig
 ]

patterns.forEach((pattern) => {
console.log(pattern.test(text))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что надо начало и конец строки проверять:

```
/^.{1,3}$/
```